# Remove mySQL row if 1 field is found

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL table called "clients" with this structure:

Name | Phone | ID

Now I am using $_GET to extract an ID from a URL, then I would like to delete the entire row (name, phone and ID) from the database that has that ID.

How woudl I do this last part (selecting the row and removing it)? I've tried some stuff but I am starting with php and mysql and it's kind of confusing.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
Delete from tableName where ID='$id'

Comment: GET operations should not be performing deletes. But it's not *my* database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this could help you out to understand better :)

```
<?php
$Action=$_REQUEST['a'];
$ID=$_REQUEST['id'];//i assume your ID's are numeric so to avoid injections check for numeric
if(is_numeric($ID)){
  if($Action=="del" and $ID){
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM clients WHERE id=".$ID);
  }
  $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id=".$ID);
  while($qd = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo "Name: ".$qd['name']."<br>Phone: ".$qd['phone']."<br><a href='?a=del&id=".$qd['id']."'>Delete</a><br><br>";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Very informative security wise. Thank you for helping me get started :)

Comment: no problem, glad to help you, its small code but could explain you much :)